# Error: Unrecognized operator: $nearSphere in meteor js

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i have simple code in meteor js for find near by garages within 10 Kilometres the query works fine in my mongodb database if run it manually in robomongo it works fine but when i run it in my routes it throws an error. like this.

```
Error: Unrecognized operator: $nearSphere in meteor jsi
```

i see some blogs they said you need to call a server side method for this. so i use below code to call a server side route.

```
Router.route('/search/:name',
                    {name:'searchlist',
                        data:function(){

                            var searchedParams = this.params.name.split('-');

                            var lat = searchedParams.pop();
                            var lng = searchedParams.pop(1);

                            return {searchValue: Centers.find({ coordinates: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng,lat] }, $maxDistance: 10000 } } })} 
                            }   
                        }, { where: "server" }


                    );
```

if anyone have idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing definitions for client and server side routes.

Server-side route **should** look like this:

```
Router.route('/search/:name', function(...){...}, { where: 'server' });
```

Client-side route *could* look like this:

```
Router.route('/search/:name, { ... });
```

Thus, your route is actually client-side route and minimongo doesn't have support for `$nearSphere` operator as noted here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/minimongo/NOTES

Answer (score 0):

First, look at Styx answer and make the route a client route by eliminating this part:

```
', { where: "server" }'
```

Now that the router is available to the client, let's fix the $nearSphere issue, by changing the operator to $near. Use the following code:

```
Centers.find(
  {
    geoloc: {
      $near: {
        $geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [lng, lat]
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Give it a try and let me know if it works.