# how to call a method of server folder from client folder in meteor js

Tags: meteor

I am new to MeteorJs and I want to call a query which should be only run on server. So I write method in server side code, but it throws an error like this:

> Error invoking Method 'getCenters': Internal server error [500]

I want to get data from collection from server side beacause $nearSphere is not working client side. Below, I added my code what I have done till now. I have two files in different directories.

Client side code, in `projectName/client/templates/pages/search.js`:

```
Template.searchlist.onRendered(function(){
    this.searchedString = Router.current().params.name;
    Meteor.call('getCenters',this.searchedString);
});
```

Server Side Code, in `myproject/server/main.js`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    Meteor.methods({
        'getCenters': function(searchedParams) {
            searchedParams = searchedParams.split('-');
            var lat = searchedParams.pop();
            var lng = searchedParams.pop(1);
            console.log(Centers.find({
                coordinates: {
                    $nearSphere: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [lng, lat]
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 10000
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This question seems as consequence of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751007/error-unrecognized-operator-nearsphere-in-meteor-js. You would do well to mark its answer as accepted.

Comment: that is also my question but not working that one. because i want to use client side router method

Comment: You have to show the error log here. Just go in your shell or server and add here the error-trace from there

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you define your methods in Meteor.startup of main.js.

You shouldn't do that. Create a separated file in server folder to put your methods in. Your main.js should be empty except `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';`

Another point : Meteor.methods `console.log` will be shown in server console. So you won't see the result in the browser console.

You don't have any callback in your client-side call so there will be no result in the client...

Comment: ok thank you @GregBzFullstack getting some ideas from you ! if i create a file like this `prjectName/server/newJs.js ` so do i need to include this file somewhere. i am just little bit confusing

Comment: No, it will be automatically included by Meteor. It's a very smart framework !!! You're methods will be accessible from everywhere in the client.
Maybe you should just put the console.log in your method to test the access. And look in the server console for the result !

Comment: hi @GregBzFullstack i just added  but is shows error message like this `Error invoking Method 'getResponseFromServer': Method 'getResponseFromServer' not found [404]`

Comment: Sometimes, I need to shutdown the server and restart it to apply changes server-side. Maybe you should try because I don't understand...

Comment: let me share you what i did    `getResponseFromServer = function(){
return 5+3;
}` and then calling this method from my iron router like this `console.log(Meteor.call('getResponseFromServer'));` and it is showing me error

Comment: You can't do this. Calling a Meteor.method DOES NOT return value to client-side. To test your call, put `console.log("Calling my server method");` inside the method on server side. On client side, just call the method `Meteor.call('getResponseFromServer');`. If it works, you should see on the SERVER console : Calling my server method" but nothing will happen client-side.

Comment: You can look for methods at [link](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html).
If you want to use a return client side, you need to create a stub (a kind off callback) like this : `// Asynchronous call
Meteor.call('foo', 1, 2, (error, result) => { ... });`

Comment: i got my response in server console but if i return from server i dont see anything in my client side helper.

Comment: OK, that's a good news ! Try my last comment. But using methods can be a little bit difficult and sometimes, you'd better implement your method as a function client-side. Good luck and check the answer as OK.

Comment: i still get response from server but not able to get in my client method even i used code this. `Meteor.call("getResponseFromServer",latlong,function(success,error){
  console.log(success+' see sucess here');
  console.log(error+' see failure here');
 });`

Comment: Sorry for numerous comments but still can't go to chat... Do you method returns something ? Be carreful, the order of the arguments in callback is error, response...

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like you're sending `string` to the meteor method, but treating it as `array` (using `.pop()`)
2. Where do you import/create collection `Centers`?
3. `Collection.find()` returns cursor. To fetch documents you need to use `.fetch()` on this cursor.

Comment: i admit your all point @Styx  actucally i am using var `searchedParams = searchedParams.split('-'); ` beofre split i am sorry for that the main thing is that i am not able to call this function

Comment: Your error is with _invoking_ this method, not the inability to invoke it. That's why you should show your actual code, otherwise it would be very hard to help you.